# Show multiline PROMPT after clearing terminal Mac OS using zsh

Tags: zsh, command-prompt, macos-catalina

I have made a custom PROMPT that uses multiple lines in my .zshcr file

```
PROMPT="%(1V.(%1v)"$'\n'".)%F{166}%n%f at %F{229}%m%f in %F{114}%.%f"$'\n'"$ "
```

but when I clear the terminal using `command+K` only the last line is shown in the cleared terminal. So I wonder if anyone knows what I need to add to have the full PROMPT shown in the cleared terminal

Comment: Does the same happen with Ctrl+Cmd+L, or using the `clear` command? If you're customising your terminal, you may also be interested in iTerm2 (this behaviour might be unique to Terminal.app).

Comment: Yes the same happens if I use Ctrl+Cmd+L @Blieque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. This activates Zsh's [`clear-screen` widget](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-clear_002dscreen).

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for @marlon

Answer (score 0):

The terminal emulator isn't aware of where the prompt starts and ends, and so can only offer the scrolling behaviour you experience. I believe the terminal emulator just scrolls the current contents of the window up until the cursor hits the top of the screen, or potentially clears the contents completely.

Running the `clear` command will get you the result you want. This program performs a similar scrolling operation, then exits and returns control to the shell, which then draws your prompt, just like it does after running any command. I've tested this in Bash, but I think it would apply to Zsh too.