# Clear terminal without clearing first line of multi-line prompt

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I'm trying to setup the terminal on my new Mac to match the behavior of my old Mac, however I have run into an issue with my multiline prompt that has me stumped. I remember having this issue when I setup my old Mac several years ago, however I don't remember how I solved it.

My prompt (without color) looks like this:

```zsh
╭─username ~                                   130 ↵
╰─
```

When I press <kbd>⌘command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> in iTerm2 on my old Mac it clears the terminal window so that both lines of the prompt are shown at the top.

When I press <kbd>⌘command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> in iTerm2 on my new Mac it clears the terminal window so that only the second line of the prompt is shown at the top.

I have tried checking everything I could think of, I have checked:

- Every dot file/directory in my home directory (copied them to the new Mac).
- iTerm2 settings.
- System settings (primarily keyboard shortcuts).
- Various websites with instructions about setting up multi-line prompts.

Interestingly I have discovered that if I type `clear` iTerm2 will clear the screen and leave the top line showing on both Macs. However it first clears the entire screen, including the prompt, before bringing the prompt back (looks bad imo). However since it works differently <kbd>⌘command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> does I don't think that's what my old Mac is doing.

It's possible that I installed some program/script that somehow does this, but if so I'm not finding it locally or referenced online.

Does anyone know how I can get <kbd>⌘command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> working to clear the screen while keeping the top line of my prompt? I still have the old Mac so I can check/compare anything on it to the new Mac if there are any guesses about what settings I changed.

Edit:
I was able to find something that worked, however if anyone has any other suggestions I'll be happy to try them and accept any that I can make work that are less hacky than this (e.g. don't require another 3rd party app).

Comment: Does [this](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/1330#note_402495779) help you? `Enable "Redraw the screen after the Clear Buffer menu item is selected" under Preferences -> Advanced -> General`

Comment: That ends up with my top line being drawn twice. That might be caused by how I got my multiline prompt working in the past though, so I'll see if I can figure out a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have iTerm2's [shell integration](https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html) installed? It's what provides this functionality:

> Shell Integration works by configuring your shell on each host you log into to send special escape codes that convey the following information:
>
> - Where the command prompt begins and ends.
> - Where a command entered at the command prompt ends and its output begins.
>   [...]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This doesn't work while a command is running, nor does it clear the scrollable history. So it's better than nothing but still doesn't behave like I want it to.

After coming back to my question SO associated a new question with an answer I was able to make work, although it feels extra hacky and wasn't what I had working before.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65797386/1191847) which suggests using <kbd>⌃control</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to clear the screen. That does exactly what I want it to do (leaves the top prompt visible and doesn't flash) but with the wrong keybinding. Fortunately I was able to use an app I already have installed ([BTT](https://folivora.ai)) to make <kbd>⌘command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> map to <kbd>⌃control</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> only in iTerm2.